# Axiom of replacement examples

Tags: set-theory, axioms, foundations

I've been trying to understand the axiom of replacement for quite a while now, I really don't get it, I don't understand how it can be used to show that a class is a set in ZF.
My textbook gives me this definition:

[image]

I don't understand how this $\phi(s,t)$ formula has to be chosen and what it has to look like.

An example (that is not really an exmaple, since it's used in a proof) this book gives me is:

"Call $g$ an $n$-function, $g_n$, for $n∈ℕ$, if the following hold:

1. $g$ is a function
2. the domain of $g$ is the set $n^+$
3. $g(0)=y_0$
4. for all $i∈n$, $g$ satisfies the rule $g(i^+)=h(i,g(i))$

define $f$ to be: $f=⋃\{g_n:n∈ℕ\}$

We must show that this $f$ is a set in ZF. This follows from the union axiom once we have shown that $\{g_n:n∈ℕ\}$ is a set. And this latter follow from the axiom of replacement taking the formula $\phi(s,t)$ to be $(s∈ℕ→(t$ is an $s$-function$))∧(s∉ℕ→t=∅)$

We have shown that for each natural number $n$ there is a unique $n$-function so that $\phi(s,t)$ is a class function. Taking $x$ in the axiom of replacement to be the set $ℕ$, the resulting set of images is $\{g_n:n∈ℕ\}$, so that the latter is indeed a set."

But I still don't understand why that $\phi(s,t)$ is like that.

Can you guys give me an easier example for applying this theorem? for example, how can i prove that $\{1,2,3\}$ is a a set in ZF? How do i define this set $y$ such that $∃x'∈\{1,2,3\}∧\phi(x',y')$ where $\phi(x',y')$ is a class function?

Thank you!

Comment: The gist of $\phi(s,t)$ is that we want a class function, which returns *the* $s$-function if $s\in\mathbb{N}$. (I *believe* you know that the $n$-function is unique for each $n$.) Since we do not care the value of this class function for $s\notin\mathbb{N}$, we may take it the empty set.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as the axiom of replacement; it's the *axiom schema* of replacement. This means each binary predicate $\phi$ on sets contributes its own axiom to the schema. In particular, it would be more helpful to write the schema's special case with a given $\phi$ as$$\color{red}{(\forall s\exists t(\phi(s,\,t)\land\forall t^\prime(\phi(s,\,t^\prime)\to t^\prime=t)))}\to\color{blue}{(\forall x\exists y\forall y^\prime(y^\prime\in y\iff\exists x^\prime(x^\prime\in x\land\phi(x^\prime,\,y^\prime))))}.$$A typical proof strategy is to choose a $\phi$ for which you can prove the red part, so we then get the blue part from the relevant axiom within the schema. In fact, we can change the red part to$$\forall s\forall t\forall t^\prime(\phi(s,\,t)\land\phi(s,\,t^\prime)\to t^\prime=t),$$i.e. $\phi$ doesn't have to be satisfiable for all $s$.

Comment: There is a subtle difference though between the function and partial function (in your last sentence) versions of the axiom schema: The latter can be used to produce the empty set from any set, the former can't by itself

Comment: Yeah my problem is that i don't understand what the blue part does, the red one pretty much just says that $t$ has to be unique, the blue part says that for every set $x$ there is a set $y$ whose elements are the elements that satisfy the formula $\phi(x', y')$ where $x'$ are elements of $x$ and $y'$ are elements of $y$. I don't really get what this axiom does and what this formula has to mean

Comment: @AndreaBurgio It lets you write a set of the form $\{f(x^\prime)|x^\prime\in x\}$, where $f(x^\prime)$ is the unique $y^\prime$ with $\phi(x^\prime,\,y^\prime)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The upshot of this is which axioms of Zermelo set theory can be deleted from ZF due to becoming theorems.